# Java filedialog always prepends /Users/<user>/Desktop in Mac

Tags: java, awt, filechooser

I'm using `System.setProperty("apple.awt.fileDialogForDirectories", "true");` to only select folders. When I execute `new java.io.File(fd.getFile()).getAbsolutePath();`, it always returns `/Users/<user>/Desktop/<folder>`. Say I select /Users, it will return `/Users/<user>/Desktop/Users`. How can I fix it?

Code:

```
if (System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("mac")) {
        System.setProperty("apple.awt.fileDialogForDirectories", "true");

        FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(this, "Choose a folder to save streams", FileDialog.LOAD);
        fd.setDirectory(saveStreamLocTB.getText());

        fd.setVisible(true);

        String loc = new java.io.File(fd.getFile()).getAbsolutePath();
        if (loc != null) {
            p.setSaveStreamLoc(loc);
            saveStreamLocTB.setText(loc);
        }

        System.setProperty("apple.awt.fileDialogForDirectories", "false");
    }
```

**edit** I need the full path

Comment: Why are you using `apple.awt`? Java provides a [cross-platform file-chooser dialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) that can be easily configured to only select folders.

Comment: If you don't want an absolute path, why are you using `getAbsolutePath()`?

Answer (score 1):

`fd.getFile()` returns a relative path, and [`new File()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File-java.lang.String-) will create a new `File` *relative to the execution directory*:

> By default the classes in the `java.io` package always resolve relative pathnames against the current user directory. This directory is named by the system property `user.dir`, and is typically the directory in which the Java virtual machine was invoked.

So by the time you call `.getAbsolutePath()` the path you're working with is already mangled.

Calling `fd.getDirectory() + fd.getFile()` works, but you should avoid constructing file paths with string concatenation - that's what the [two-argument `File` constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) is for, so instead do:

```
String loc = new File(fd.getDirectory(), fd.getFile()).getAbsolutePath();
```

---

That said Java 7 introduced the much more flexible and powerful [`Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathClass.html) class, and wherever possible I'd suggest using it over `File`. Along the same lines Swing includes a [cross-platform file-chooser dialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) that will be much easier to work with than Apple's old `awt` APIs. There's also [`DirectoryChooser`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/DirectoryChooser.html) if you want to try JavaFX.

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

This

```
String loc = new java.io.File(fd.getFile()).getAbsolutePath();
```

needed to be this

```
String loc = fd.getDirectory() + fd.getFile();
```